# storing output from piped cmd into string (bash)

Tags: string, bash, shell

I am trying to put the output of a bash command (filename) into a string for later access.

```
echo "$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)"
```

successfully prints out the latest file updated in the directory (good).

The problem occurs when I try to store this into a var. to access later in the script.

Any suggestions on how to do so?  I've seen different methods, but it didn't seem to work/ apply because I'm using the param -Art for ls.

Thanks!

further info:   filename still gets kicked back as the {actual filename}: **command not found**

```
filename = `ls -Art | tail -n 1`
```

Comment: I assume you want something like this, in which case I don't see the problem unless you're using assignment incorrectly:
`$ x=$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)

$ echo $x
`

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) says "[Don't put spaces around the =](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1068) in assignments."

Comment: thanks!  @thatotherguy

Answer (score 0):

> shellcheck says "Don't put spaces around the = in assignments." –
>   that other guy 1 min ago

@that-other-guy  was correct.  It had to do with the spaces around the '='

Thanks!